# In a Rails App, how can I make the presence of text in a certain form field lead to one image showing, but if blank, another shows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, if-statement

I'm posting reviews for Amazon products since it's become a crapshoot if you're getting a legit product or cheap garbage straight from China. If the product is legit, I want the Amazon 'buy' image (that's linked to the item) to appear. If it's garbage, I want a different Amazon image to appear (a greyed out one).

I have 'verdict' and 'goodverdict' fields in my new product form. But atm only verdict is in use, and the Amazon buy image is always there (these two are not related right now).

What I've been trying to do is set it up so if I fill out the 'goodverdict' field, the buy image shows (with a link). Conversely, if I use the regular 'verdict' field and leave 'goodverdict' blank, then the greyed out image shows.

I think all I'm missing is an if/else statement?

I removed any styling, but this is the verdict showing and under it, the buy image that's linked to the product (I paste that 'buylink' link into the form). This is in a partial that renders on the product show page.

```
<div>
<h1><%= @product.verdict %></h1><br>
<%= link_to image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon-Button.png"), @product.buylink.html_safe %>
</div>
```

If you want to see the form fields:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :buylink %>
<%= f.text_field :buylink, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :verdict %>
<%= f.text_field :verdict, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :goodverdict %>
<%= f.text_field :goodverdict, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

I'm open to alternative ways of doing this, like a checkbox for "crap" or "legit" being what controls if the buy image shows. I welcome all good advice. Thank you in advance.

Attempt at ternary operator:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="belowvid">
<%= @product.verdict.present? ?
<h1 id="showverdict"> @product.verdict </h1><br> image_tag 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon+gray+button.jpg', width: 275 : <h1 id="showverdict"> @product.goodverdict </h1><br>
link_to image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon-Button.png", width: 275), @product.buylink.html_safe, target: :_blank %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `link_to_if` for `if-else` in links.

For eg:
 `<%= link_to_if @product.verdict.present?, image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon-Button.png"), @product.buylink.html_safe %>`

or use the ternary operator:

```
<% my_url = @product.verdict.present? ? verdict image url : another image url %>
```

& then use it like 
`<%= link_to image_tag(my_url), @product.buylink.html_safe %>`

Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: that worked to make the image active/inactive as a link in the right situation, but doesn't do anything to replace the image. Do I put an 'else' somewhere for the other situation? Or just copy/paste and change 'goodverdict' to 'verdict' and the S3 image link to the alternate image? (ie no else)?

Comment: You can write the same for other condition

Comment: You can also use ternary operator like make a variable my_url = @product.verdict.present? ? verdict image url : another image url  & then just use link_to image_tag(my_url), @product.buylink.html_safe

Comment: I looked up ternary operators and this is really cool, thank you for introducing me to this concept. My only points of confusion are the my_url =, and making that work in rails as erb. I'm having a tough time... I'll add my code to the OP

(writing the same for the other condition will produce one link, but two images...)

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect!